# Lifestyle need not being met?

Tags: anno-2070

So I have 1,470 Eco Employees, and my warehouse on the island has 85 tons of Communicators in it, but my Eco Employee Lifestyle need is stuck at 0%...

Any tips?

Comment: Can't doublecheck right now, but are you sure that it's Communicators they need?

Comment: Yea, when I hover over the semicircle progress bar thing it says "Communicator. Need for Lifestyle 0/100% satisfied"

Comment: Hmm.  Are those communicators staying on the island?  I've had problems with trading them away through some automated transports I set up.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have blocked access to Communicators from your Eco Employees. You can allow/disallow your Eco Employees to Communicators by clicking an Eco Residence's house, clicking on the Lifestyle tab and then clicking on the Communicator icon. You can tell if you have blocked access to an item by the little red x near the item.

You can also do this for other consumables (like fish for example).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Idf.png]